# How can I check if a string has the same characters? Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I need to be able to discern if a string of an arbitrary length, greater than 1 (and only lowercase), has the same set of characters within a base or template string.

For example, take the string "aabc": "azbc" and "aaabc" would be false while "acba" would be true.

Is there a fast way to do this in python without keeping track of all the permutations of the first string and then comparing it to the test string?

Comment: Does it matter if there are repetitions? How would `aaaaaaabc` compare?

Comment: That would be false, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Creating all the permutations may be faster if you are testing lots of values against the same key. It'll cost a lot of extra memory though.

Comment: @MonteCarlo: It's a bit misleading to talk about "sets" when repetition matters.

Comment: @gnibbler: Storing the permutations in a compressed trie or a hash tree instead of a hash table could be an interesting tradeoff.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sort the two strings and then compare them:

```
sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)
```

If the strings might not be the same length, you might want to make sure of that first to save time:

```
len(str1) == len(str2) and sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)
```

Comment: The optimization you added may be useful, but then so may lots of other things (e.g., `str1 == str2 or sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)`); I wouldn't bother adding the complexity unless you know it's a bottleneck and you know something about the data.

Comment: @abarnert: I did note that's true only if the two aren't the same length. If the strings are long, it would probably save time even if only a minority aren't equal.

Comment: Thank you so much, I new there must have been a more intuitive way than make all the permutations, and the checking each single permutation to the template or test string.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Sure, it would probably save time, but if the saved time doesn't matter, it's not worth the added complexity.

Answer (score 5):

This is the `O(n)` solution

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)
```

But the `O(n * log n)` solution using `sorted` is likely faster for sensible values of `n`

Comment: I dunno why but this solution actually seems quite slow according to my timeit tests. Perhaps too much overhead? I've provided the test results in my answer.

Comment: @Joowani, yes `Counter` is quite slow for what it does - but then there's less chance for bugs, so it's a tradeoff. Maybe someone will optimise it better someday

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on @Joowani's solution that only uses one dictionary and runs even faster (at least on my machine) :

```
def cmp4(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False
    d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for c in str1:
        d[c] += 1
    for c in str2:
        d[c] -= 1
    return all(v == 0 for v in d.itervalues())
```

Comment: Awesome! +10 I've confirmed that this runs faster on my machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another O(n) solution, longer but slightly faster than others:

```
def cmp(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False

    d, d2 = {}, {}
    for char in str1:
        if char not in d:
            d[char] = 1
        else:
            d[char] += 1
    for char in str2:
        if char not in d:
            return False
        if char not in d2:
            d2[char] = 1
        else:
            d2[char] += 1

    return d == d2
```

It basically does the same thing as gnibber's solution (but for some strange reasons the **Counter()** from collections library seems quite slow). Here are some timeit results:

```
setup = '''
import collections
from collections import Counter

s1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" * 10000
s2 = s1[::-1]

def cmp1(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False

    d, d2 = {}, {}
    for char in str1:
        if char not in d:
            d[char] = 1
        else:
            d[char] += 1
    for char in str2:
        if char not in d:
            return False
        if char not in d2:
            d2[char] = 1
        else:
            d2[char] += 1
    return d == d2

def cmp2(str1, str2):
    return len(str1) == len(str2) and sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)

def cmp3(str1, str2):    
    return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)

def cmp4(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False
    d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for c in str1:
        d[c] += 1
    for c in str2:
        d[c] -= 1
    return all(v == 0 for v in d.itervalues())
'''

    timeit.timeit("cmp1(s1, s2)", setup=setup, number = 100)
    8.027034027221656
    timeit.timeit("cmp2(s1, s2)", setup=setup, number = 100)
    8.175071701324946
    timeit.timeit("cmp3(s1, s2)", setup=setup, number = 100)
    14.243422195893174
    timeit.timeit("cmp4(s1, s2)", setup=setup, number = 100)
    5.0937542822775015
```

Also, David's solution comes out on top when the string sizes are small and they actually have same characters.

EDIT: updated the test results

Comment: You can use `d, d2 = dict.from_keys(str1), dict.from_keys(str2)` Then you won't have to do the `in` test in the loops

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very long string, the following solution will be helpful with O(n) time complexity. You can also use an hash map/dictionary instead of the arrays/lists.

```
s1 = "sjkhdfkaljdhfaldflflad"
s2 = "lsdhfuisfslffsdjdkllja"

if len(s1)!=len(s2):
   return False

ds1 = [0] * 26
ds2 = [0] * 26

for i in range(len(s1)):
   ds1[ord(s1[i])-ord("a")] +=1 
   ds2[ord(s2[i])-ord("a")] +=1

return ds1 == ds2
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres a different way. By using what we ignore the most "sets":

```
if len(set(str1) - set(str2)) == 0:
    print "Yes"
```

Comment: This only works if the frequency of the characters doesn't matter.